# Adjusting bootstrap dropdown with textbox to content width

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have attached a fiddle with bootstrap dropdown. The dropdown has input text at the top.
How can I adjust the width of textbox and dropdown container to fit the content size? For e.g. I have a long text 'ASPHALT LAY DOWN MACHINE LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG'. The content should not wrap.

And of course there must be a max-width.

```
<div class="editableDropdown input-group">
<input type="text" class="col-md-3 gui-input" name="load" id="load"/>
<div style="display:inline-block; width:10px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:20px">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span><span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="color-dropdown-menu"
        class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right scrollable-menu" role="menu">
        <li>Select / Enter Load</li>
        <li>ARTICULATED DUMP TRUCK</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haribalaji/jk9x07dr/46/

Comment: When I went to look at your JSFiddle, I couldn't select any of the options in the dropdown. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, I did not include ng-click in the <li> options. Angular ng-click will populate the textbox based on selection.

Comment: Is there a way to include that? It's often easier to answer a question that has a working fiddle.

Comment: Modified the fiddle

Comment: would this help you? http://www.brianchu.com/blog/2013/11/02/creating-an-auto-growing-text-input/

Comment: yes, looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

it think  "select" component can solve your problem.

```
  <select>
  <option>ASPHALT MILL</option>
  <option> ASPHALT LAY DOWN MACHINE "LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG" </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: no, I cannot use select. I need textbox in the top where user can type in, rather than a read only select.